# Delete text in search field after selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

How can the text in an input field be deleted after the user selected an entry from autocompletion?

This is what I tried so far. Unfortunately this don't work (the text in the input field stays and no error occurs).

```
<script>
var data = ["foo","bar"];

$(function () {
            $("#searchField").autocomplete({
                source: data,
                minLength: 2,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                  console.log("selected: " + ui.item.label);
                  clearSearchField();
                }
            });
        });

function clearSearchField() {
            document.getElementById('searchField').value = '';
}
</script>
<input type="text" id="searchField" name="name" placeholder="Search"/>
```

Run the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/e6nj8ekz/2/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to return false after clearSearchField();

```
clearSearchField();
return false
```

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/e6nj8ekz/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Add a short timeout :

```
function clearSearchField() {
  setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById('searchField').value = '';
    },0)
}
```